# Safe way to wire CMOS ICs together

Tags: resistors, integrated-circuit, cmos, current-limiting

I have a question about the safety (to the ICs) of wiring the output of one IC directly to the input of another IC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frQCn4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For instance, in the above simple circuit we wire the output of IC1 (\$Q_{1,2}\$) to the input of IC2 (\$I_{1,2}\$). My understanding is that the gates inside the IC act as a buffer such that if the gate is active it acts as a voltage source at \$V_{CC}\$ volts, however, in this case, the connection between the output of one IC and the input of the other has approximately \$0\,\Omega\$ resistance and therefore will drastically exceed the current rating of the ICs.

Is this actually a safe way to wire up ICs or is a current-limiting resistor required, and in each case, why is this the case?

Comment: What you're missing is that normally the CMOS input will have a very high impedance, so while the wire has a small resistance very little current will flow into the pin.

Comment: @PeterJ What is the usual nominal impedance of a CMOS input; I looked through some of the datasheets for the ICs I'm using and they don't mention it?

Comment: Only outputs act as voltage sources and can sink or source current. Inputs don't care what voltage you apply (within limits), and sink or source very little current.

Comment: What ICs are you using?

Comment: @gwideman 74HC4511 (BCD to 7-segment) and 74HC04 (Hex inverter).

Comment: Input current probably about 0.1 to 1 microamp

Comment: It's listed in the "DC Electrical Characteristics" in a sheet I looked at

Comment: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT04.pdf Table 6 Static characteristics Input leakage current

Comment: @gwideman Okay, thank you; I didn't realise that was what was meant by input leakage current; so just to clarify, that's the current that will go through the input if 6.0V is connected directly to it? (With \$V_{CC}=6.0\text{ V}\$ and \$V_{I}=\{0,V_{CC}\}\$)

Comment: There's also an input capacitance (here 3.5pF), which can be important when trying to switch inputs rapidly... 100's of MHz.

Comment: @Shakal  Well, 5V would be a more recommended supply voltage, though HC family are apparently OK at 6V. And yes, if you connect a voltage in the range of 0V to Vcc to an input, that's the input current you can expect.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the limits on the datasheet (such as 100nA) are **grossly** higher than what you'd actually expect from an undamaged IC at room temperature. Typical input current for a CD4001 is about 10pA, not 100nA~1uA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMOS devices normally have a high input impedance. For the 74xx and similar logic series this information is often provided in a family guide instead of being repeated in each datasheet. For example the [Philips 74HC/HCT/HCU family](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/HCT_USER_GUIDE.pdf) guide shows on page 6 the following that indicates a maximum input current of 1uA for the 74HCXXX series:

[image: 74HCXXX maximum input current]

So while your wire will have a very small resistance in reality very little current will flow into the input pin, so it's a safe and common thing to do.

Comment: And a point to note here is that the old 7400 and 74LS series had very appreciable input current requirements, particularly in the low state. (LS, 0.4mA to 0.8mA) This limited the number of inputs that a single output could drive ("fanout") to about 10.  With CMOS, there is essentially no such hard limit.